# Conditional paperclip presence verification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, paperclip, paperclip-validation

How can I verify a paperclip attachment does *not* exist if another field does exist? I tried:

```
validates_attachment :img, presence: false, if: :some_other_field?
def some_other_field?
  some_other_field
end
```

Comment: This is what I settled on, but I'm still looking for a more elegant way: `validates :img_file_name, absence: true, if: :some_other_field?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar problem here, my solution was to make the comparison in the def

```
validate :check_image_with_title 

def check_image_with_title
   if !ctitle.blank? and cimage.blank?
      #If ctitle IS NOT empty and cimage IS empty, add a custom error message
      errors.add :key, "You need an image to go with your title"
      return false
    else
      return true
   end 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
validates_attachment :img, presence: true, if: :some_other_field?
def some_other_field?
  some_other_field.present?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `exists?` instead `present?`, could be works

```
validates_attachment :img, presence: false, if: :some_other_field?
def some_other_field?
  some_other_field.exists?
end
```

Comment: Just tried it this way as well as techvineet's way and Aman's way. No dice.